# Positioning a figure in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word

My goal is to put a figure including its caption at a fixed position on the page, ideally at the top of the page and make it there, no matter the weather outside. For no logical reason, caption floats completely independently of figure, so that is the first issue, then I do not want the text to float around, i want the figure to separate the text as indicated below.

What I have seem to mitigate the issue with caption is to use a legacy feature called frames to keep the figure and caption together. It is really awful and does not solve the second issue. Has this been figured out or such simple thing (from e.g. LaTeX point of view) is not possible in Word?

```
text
text
|----------|
|          |
|  FIGURE  |
|          |
|..........|
| Caption  |
|----------|
text
text
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to group the picture and caption, and then use absolute positioning for the layout.

1. Create your picture, use absolute positioning.
   [image: absolute positioning]
2. Create your caption for the picture, right click -> **Insert Caption...**
   [image: enter caption dialog]
3. Group the image and caption. Select one, hold shift, then the other, then right click and chose **Group**:

   [image]

Now the caption should stay with the group regardless of where you position it.

[image]